# WKWebView Swift - Make screenshot of website without the fixed menu bar

Tags: swift, wkwebview

I'm using Xcode Swift 3 and WKWebView to display the websites. Then I try to screen capture the website using the following code that I've found from the Internet. There are some websites that come with a fixed menu bar either at the top or bottom of the website. Hence, as I scroll the website, the menu bar does not move with the browser and is fixed on the screen. The problem is this fixed menu bar of the website appears on my screenshot. Is there a way to make a screenshot without the fixed menu bar? Thanks in advance for your help.

```
func snapshot(of rect: CGRect? = nil) -> UIImage? {
    // snapshot entire view

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(bounds.size, isOpaque, 0)
    drawHierarchy(in: bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)
    let wholeImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    // if no `rect` provided, return image of whole view

    guard let image = wholeImage, let rect = rect else { return wholeImage }

    // otherwise, grab specified `rect` of image

    let scale = image.scale
    let scaledRect = CGRect(x: rect.origin.x * scale, y: rect.origin.y * scale, width: rect.size.width * scale, height: rect.size.height * scale)
    guard let cgImage = image.cgImage?.cropping(to: scaledRect) else { return nil }
    return UIImage(cgImage: cgImage, scale: scale, orientation: .up)
}
```

Comment: You could probably use `WKWebView`'s `evaluateJavaScript()` method to run a script that deletes unwanted elements from the DOM. However, you'd probably need to be tailoring the script to individual websites rather than a generalized solution.

Comment: It works for some websites. I can hide the header by changing the display of the CSS file. I will continue to explore other possible solutions. Thanks.